# Proof of representation of a subset of real numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, real-numbers

I apologize for the poor title, if anyone can think of a better one and a better tag I would appreciate it. I am trying to prove this statement, which I need to complete a step in a proof.

Let $(y_1,\dots,y_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\{a_{ij} \mid 1\leq i \leq n,1\leq j \leq n\}$ be set of fixed real numbers such that for each $i$, there exists a $j$ such that $a_{ij}\neq 0$, and similarly, for each $j$, there exists a $i$ such that $a_{ij}\neq 0$.Then there exist $x_1,\dots x_n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $y_i=\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} x_j$ for each $1 \leq i \leq n$.

I have played around with it and cannot get anywhere at all. Any ideas?

Comment: This is a system of $n$ linear equations with $n$ variables. Apply  [Rouche-Frobenius or Rouche-Capeli Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem)

Comment: @TitoEliatron Thank you for this! Would you be able to expand on this a bit? I don't think it's possible to calculate the rank without knowing the specific values for the $a_{ij}$ so I'm not sure how to apply this to my problem.

Comment: Obviuosly, it depends on the rank of the coefficients. For example if $a_{ij}=0$ for all $i,j$, and some $y_k\ne0$, them it is impossible to get your desiresd $x_1,...,x_n$. I mean. If $Rank(A)=Rank(A|y)=n$ then there is a unique $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$. If $Rank(A)=Rank(A|y)=k<n$ there are infinitely many $x$. If both ranks are different, there is no such $x$.

Comment: @TitoEliatron Thank you, I actually misstated the problem. There should also be the condition that $\det(a_{ij})\neq 0$, so that each row and column contains a nonzero element. Can anything be said in this case?

Comment: If $det(A)\ne0$, Rouche-Capeli guaratees the existence of a unique $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ and you're done. But your conditions do NOT say that. Take $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&2\\2&4\end{pmatrix}$ and $y_1=y_2=1$.

Comment: @TitoEliatron I see, thanks! Just to clarify, what part of Rouche-Capeli gives the result?